# Answer or vote to close or delete simple questions?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I have a doubt and want some clarification on the community.

I answered a question where the user was getting a value by using an incorrect variable name. Instead of `pizzaname` he was supposed to use `pizza`.

I just got a comment:

> This is a friendly reminder that it's not worth answering typo questions. You are wasting your time and such questions will be deleted sooner or later. It also attracts downvotes.

My question: If my answer does not help any other developers, should I post it? Or flag the question to be closed?

This case is very specific and simple, and the users is relatively new, but I feel that if I can help anyone no matter how simple or difficult the question is, I will.

Link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586043/why-my-php-code-is-not-inserting-data-i-want-instead-leaving-it-blank/62586217?noredirect=1#comment110704743_62586217) in case you want to see it.

Comment: Note that this isn't just a case of "simple question". When it isn't just a typo, you can vote accordingly, look for duplicates, and either vote to close it as one or answer anyway. There is no "too simple" reason for closing a question, but there is one for never being useful to future readers.

Comment: It's the similar, I went and saw the Tutorial at the beginning and didn't saw anything related to not answer in fact it mention that we should answer other developers questions. I understand that this is a one person solution, but because of it I should ignore it and not give him/her any feedback because it does not help other users ? and instead flag to close or delete ? my question still prevails ..

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer and in the comment below my answer, nothing stops you from leaving feedback as comments and help the user. You can help and yet refrain from posting answers to questions that are not fit for the site. You got the feedback earlier, not sure why you say you didn’t.

Answer (score 13):

The idea is to build a repository of useful question and answers. The majority of users can find answers to their questions without posting any question themselves. Simply because many similar questions were asked before.

Typo questions are not useful for future visitors. Answering helps only the question asker, but it detracts from the site's quality because they add **noise**, making it harder to find actually useful information on the site.

So when you find a question that's predicated on a simple error, just post a helpful comment and flag to close the question. That way you help the user asking the question (we've all been there, typos come with the territory), and help curate the site, and in the process help countless future users.

That the user is "new" is not relevant: rules are the same for everyone. And that the question is "simple" is not the issue. A question can be "simple" and yet be fit for the site.

The problem with typo question is not their simplicity (at least in regards to topicality), but that they are simply not useful for other users. Other users will make different mistakes, and will use different keywords to try to find a solution to their problems.

Comment: to understand this correctly, then I flag it to close and don't spend any time on answering it?

Comment: If you want, you can comment to help the OP. But answering questions that are not fit for the site is frowned upon, since it makes curating the site harder.

Comment: "*Typo questions are not useful for future visitors.*" I agree with this statement, however, there *are* exceptions. There are sometimes typos that are non-intuitive and result from language syntax peculiarities. In those cases, an answer *might* be helpful if it leads to a deeper understanding of the language. However, chances are that there is already a dupe for that. And a pretty well voted one, at that. Obscure and unintuitive things seems to be quite popular. With that said - if the answer is really "you're missing a bracket" or something to that effect, it's hardly a great mystery.

Comment: I just want to note that currently searching for answers is not like this (the purported goal) at all.  And it seems to have been getting progressively worse.  I'll say that for the last few months search results for some things feel like they have improved slightly, but searching for very simple answers just doesn't get good dupe results.  For example, searching for the whole regexp string escaping should get me the two main threads with a decent answer quickly.  It doesn't.  I only get the one.  This is only a popular example.  IMHO I don't think SO's "measures" are designed well enough.

Comment: My main point being, here in a partial and specific case example, measures to discourage cross-linking I think have acted to undermine search results by working against search engine algorithms.  Back in the day people complained about copy paste link answers.  But many of those linked articles became easier to find.  The whole signal noise thing is (IMO) like pre-optimization, because search engines were smart enough to find the "main core thread" that they all linked back to, or in a poor man's graph theory language, "highest frequency path intersection".

Comment: I'm not a mod, and I imagine for mods and very experienced SO people it's tiring and demotivating to sift through so much garbage in the content, which is uninteresting.  But at the same time, I feel as though this is like one of those arguments I commonly see where people insist on believing that they as individuals can always do better than any automated system, which they insist cannot be trusted.  And so the data, although it does tend to be kind of garbage in garbage out, becomes no data at all tainted by personal opinions of the elite, which actually ends up being worse.