# Which close vote option corresponds to "unlikely to help anyone else in the future"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Which close vote option corresponds to "unlikely to help anyone else in the future"?

As @yivi mentions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398800/answer-or-vote-to-close-or-delete-simple-questions/398801#398801),

> The idea [of Stack Overflow] is to build a repository of useful question and answers. [...]
>
> [Certain types of] questions are not useful for future visitors. Answering helps only the question asker, but it detracts from the site's quality because they add noise, making it harder to find actually useful information on the site.

Many times, simplistic and *specific* homework questions are asked on [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Even if they are formatted and well-posed, they can often have non-useful answers. Duplicates don't always exist, either.

Which close vote option should we use for such questions? I close as "too broad", but that seems to be the opposite of what I mean, which is "too specific". I recall that there were "off topic" options in the past which dealt with this frequent case, but they're not present anymore.

Comment: Well, there exists "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.", which matches the wording and reasoning you're looking for, but TBH, that sort of thing could apply to *tons* of questions here (eg "Here are 50 lines of code, please debug it for me") which are never going to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That would be my choice except for its title being "Not reproducible or caused by typo", which isn't always true.

Comment: [*"\[D\]o not pretend to be able to predict the future; close only based on the evidence in front of you."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348033) We don't have such a close reason. Unless there is an objective problem with the question, causing it to fit into one of the defined close reasons, then you should not be voting to close it. Stack Overflow is indeed building a library of Q&A, but it's to include the long tail of questions. That includes those which do not seem likely at first blush to be useful to others.